# Convert Python to Haskell / Lambda calculus

Tags: python, haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

**What is the Python code in Haskell and Lambda calculus?**

```
def f1():
   x = 77
   def f2():
      print x
   f2
f1
```

My attempt in lambda calculus

```
\x. 77 (\x.x)
```

Comment: Lambda calculus has no concept of state.  Printing involves state.

Comment: I presume you intend to return f2 and call f1, because as written your f1 returns None and is uncalled.

Comment: Also see http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/09/on-writing-python-one-liners.html

Comment: What is this Python code trying to do? It is rather stilted code. Perhaps it would be more instructive to have more realistic Python code. Or is there some particular concept in the lambda calculus you are trying understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell:

```
f1 :: IO ()
f1 = let x = 77
         f2 = print x
     in f2

main :: IO ()
main = f1
```

Or to be more like your lambda calculus:

```
f1 :: Int
f1 = let f2 = x
         x = 77
     in f2

main :: IO ()
main = print f1
```

Answer (score 8):

In Haskell:

```
f1 = f2
    where x  = 77
          f2 = print x
```

Refactoring, since IO just confuses the issue:

```
f1 = f2
    where x  = 77
          f2 = x
```

Refactoring:

```
f1 = x
    where x = 77
```

Refactoring, since you want the variable?

```
f1 = (\x -> x) 77
```

Beta reduce:

```
f1 = 77
```

And you have your program in Haskell.

Lambda calculus doesn't have numeric literals (unlike Haskell), so we must use [Church numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding).
So compiling "77" to lambda calculus:

```
f1 = \f.\x. f (f (f (f ( ... ) x)))
```

And there's your Python program in Lambda Calculus.

Comment: I guess we can optimise it to `(\three.(\seven.(\ten.\f.\x.ten (seven f) (seven f x)) (\f.\x.three f (seven f x))) (\f.\x.f (three f (three f x)))) (\f.\x.f(f(f x)))`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, so I could be completely wrong, but this is my Haskell interpretation.

```
f1 = let x = 77 in show x
```

Or, since you've got a constant there

```
f1 = show 77
```

Answer (score 1):

In lambda calculus:

```
λprint. print 77
```

Comment: The Python program doesn't take an argument for the `print` function.

Comment: Then the proper translation is `λ77. λprint. print 77`, or, if you flip the arguments, `λx.x`. :)